# Previous=current?

Tags: c++, string

I am a beginner, so this is probably a silly question.

I don't understand how this code works. If i initialize the string `previous` as an empty space, in which part of the code it becomes "the previous word" if I only read `current` as an input? I don't understand why the last statement `previous=current` is necessary.

```cpp
int main() {

    std::string previous = " "; //previous word initialized to "not a word"
    std::string current; //current word
    while (std::cin >> current) { //read a stream of words
        if (previous == current) //check if the word is the same as last
            std::cout << "repeated word:" << current << '\n';
        previous = current;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If you didn't set the previous word to the one you just read then how would you know if the next word you read is the same or not?

Comment: but how is it that "previous" becomes the previous word in the first place? if i haven´t changed its value from the "blank space" it started

Comment: Let's say you are reading "dog dog cat". You read "dog", it doesn't match " " and previous is set to "dog". You read "dog" it matches "dog" you print the duplicate then set previous to "dog". You read "cat" it doesn't match "dog" and so on.

Comment: The logic is that a string is read (to `current`).   At the end of the loop body, `previous` is assigned the same value as `current`.   Then another string is read to `current`, leaving `previous` unchanged.   If that read succeeds, execution enters the loop body, so `current` contains the most recent string read, and `previous` includes the one read before that (i.e. the previous one).     Before starting the loop `previous` is initialised to `" "` so that is deemed to be the "previous" string for the first time through the loop.

Comment: finally got it!! thank you!

Comment: @Peter maybe your comment suits best for an answer, mate.